# Remove the object definition from json array that is within an json array keeping the nested array intact

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following xml:

```
<root xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>
   <majorDimension>ROWS</majorDimension>
   <range>Sheet6!A1:B2</range>
   <values json:Array='true'>
      <element json:Array='true'>
         <element>Good</element>
         <element>Value</element>
      </element>
      <element json:Array='true'>
         <element>Hello</element>
         <element>World</element>
      </element>
   </values>
</root>
```

and I'm using the following code:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
```

The output that I am getting is like this

```
{
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "range": "Sheet6!A1:B2",
    "values": [
                  { "element": [ [ "Good", "Value" ],
                                 [ "Hello", "World" ] ]
                  }
              ]
}
```

However, I would like get an output something like this

```
{
  "range": "Sheet6!A1:B2",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
        "Good",
        "Value"
    ],
    [
        "Hello",
        "World"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None` -> `Formatting.Indented`

Comment: So you just want to remove the 'element' properties in the Values?

Comment: I want remove the element property but keep the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more details it's hard to offer a good solution. Should probably be able to deserialize into a well defined C# class and manipulate data from there. Or similar. But anyways.

---

First option, note the documentation

> Multiple nodes with the same name at the same level are grouped together into an array.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm

So you can rename all `element` to `values` and get a nested array output (one more than request), but it's missing the `{ "element" : ...`  JSON. The "element" contents are all there though.

---

Second option, manipulate XML document before converting to JSON. This lifts each child `element` node to the same level in the tree as `values`. The only consideration is that the output array is called `element` instead of `values`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string xmlDoc = @"<root xmlns:json='http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json'>
   <majorDimension>ROWS</majorDimension>
   <range>Sheet6!A1:B2</range>
   <values json:Array='true'>
      <element json:Array='true'>
         <element>Good</element>
         <element>Value</element>
      </element>
      <element json:Array='true'>
         <element>Hello</element>
         <element>World</element>
      </element>
   </values>
</root>";

var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlDoc);
var valuesObject = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("values")[0];
XmlNode parent = valuesObject.ParentNode;
while (valuesObject.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
{
    XmlNode child = valuesObject.ChildNodes[0];
    parent.InsertBefore(child, valuesObject);
}
parent.RemoveChild(valuesObject);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xdoc.ChildNodes[0], Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

output

```
{
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "range": "Sheet6!A1:B2",
  "element": [
    [
      "Good",
      "Value"
    ],
    [
      "Hello",
      "World"
    ]
  ]
}
```

---

Third option, convert XML to JSON, serialize to jobject, manipulate the structure, deserialize to string.

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlDoc);

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xdoc.ChildNodes[0], Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);
var jobj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

var elements = jobj["values"][0]["element"];
// remove existing "values" node
jobj.Remove("values");
// add a new node called "values" with the contents of the "elements" array
jobj.Add("values", elements);

Console.WriteLine(jobj.ToString());
```

output

```
{
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "range": "Sheet6!A1:B2",
  "values": [
    [
      "Good",
      "Value"
    ],
    [
      "Hello",
      "World"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace the "Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None" by "Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);
```

Comment: Please refer the question. I don't want indentation. I want the property the removed, keeping the array intact

Comment: @Saurav I don't have time to read your json in one line. You edited your question after. You did not say anything abouy a property being removed in your questions just 2 json's code.